# Basic question about complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

This is very basic question, we know that $\bar{z}=Re(z)-iIm(z)$ but this is the presentation of $\bar{z}$ and I want the presentation of $z$.. so does it mean that $z=Re(z)+iIm(z)$ or no? If so, then how can we represent this $z$?

Comment: Only I can tell you with such apprehension with your question is, $Re(\bar{z})=Re(z)$ and $Im(\bar{z})=Im(z)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct. If $z=x+iy$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, then $Re(z)=x$, and $Im(z)=y$, so we have
$$z=Re(z)+iIm(z)$$

Comment: What happens if $x$ and $y$ do not belong to real numbers but rather also complex numbers?

Comment: @user226542 If $z$ is a complex number, then it has a unique representation as a $x+iy$ where $x$ and $y$ are reals - that is why I gave it in this form. Additionally, this is how $Re(z)$ and $Im(z)$ are defined - they say that if we write the complex number $z$ in this unique form then we define $Re(z)$ to be the real number part without $i$ and $Im(z)$ to be the real number part with $i$.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Elementary_operations there is an "i" there.

Comment: @SufyanSheikh [This is the definition I know.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ImaginaryPart.html)

Comment: @user226542 yes, that is consistent with $Im(z)=y$ and not $Im(z)=iy$.

Comment: @SufyanSheikh I think the reason it is defined that way is to make it easier to use the normal structure of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ if we want to talk about $\mathbb{C}$. Still, it is a definition and often times definitions can be somewhat arbitrary. A pure imaginary number is one which can be written in the form $z=iy$, or another way of putting it is $Re(z)=0$.

Comment: Ah I see. Well, it needs a rigorous analysis to understand the philosophy underlying them

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt thank you.